# From date.today() to datetime for greater or less than another datetime python

Tags: python, datetime

When I try to run the following code, python returns an error. I think this is because date.today() isn't in the datetime format.

```
R_timer=2021-12-07 00:00:00 (in datetime format)
if date.today()>=R_timer:
    print('1')
```

Python returns: Comparison of Timestamp with datetime.date is deprecated in order to match the standard library behavior. In a future version these will be considered non-comparable. Use 'ts == pd.Timestamp(date)' or 'ts.date() == date' instead.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `R_timer` is of type `datetime.datetime`, and `date.today()` is of type `datetime.date`. Instead, try:

```py
from datetime import datetime
if datetime.today() >= R_timer:
    print('1')
```

Comment: I'm getting: module 'datetime' has no attribute 'today'

Comment: I tried this one: datetime.date.today() but python's returning the same error

Comment: It depends how you've imported `datetime.datetime`. If you've imported it with `from datetime import datetime` then `datetime.today()` will work, but if you've imported it with `import datetime`, then you need to enter `datetime.datetime.today()`.

Comment: I did import it using from datetime import datetime but datetime.today() doesn't work

Comment: Interesting. There must be multiple `import` statements causing the problem.

Comment: I've imported it multiple times: 
from datetime import date
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

Comment: Okay, well those 3 imports should work fine. Strange. I wonder what's going on.

Answer (score 0):

```
from datetime import datetime 
R_timer = datetime(2021, 12, 7, 0, 0, 0)
if datetime.today()>=R_timer:
    print('1')
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the R_timer output cannot be changed into year, month, day because its an output of another piece of code. I simplified it for the post's sake

Comment: I tried this one: datetime.date.today() but python's returning the same error

Comment: if the type of R_timer is string, you can simply extract the information that you need, convert it to Int and use datetime function to convert the type into datetime.

Comment: I'm not familiar with this, so I will try my best:
t = int(datetime.date.today().strftime('%m/%d/%Y'))
t.pd.datetime()

returns: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '06/13/2022'